# Cannot convert to NSDate from this specific date (1994-04-01) String

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

Something strange happen to me.
I'm not able to convert this specific date (1994-04-01) String.
Can anyone check this and let me know if it reproduce in your code?

Steps to Reproduce:

Swift:-

```
let dateString = "1994-04-01"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let dateFromString = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
```

Obj c:-

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *birthdayStr = @"1994-04-01";
NSDate *birthday = [formatter dateFromString:birthdayStr];
```

Expected Results:

```
birthday = 1994-03-31 21:00:00 +0000
```

In UTC

Actual Results:

```
birthday = nil
```

Version:

Xcode ver :- Version 8.1 (8B62)

OS X ver :-  10.12.1 (16B2555)

you can try any different date then (1994-04-01) and it will work fine.

Comment: Please don't post code in italics. Use code blocks instead - that's what they're there for.

Comment: @CodeDifferent: That doesn't explain the problem at all. It's not being parsed properly - that's not the same as it showing up in an unexpected time zone.

Comment: Perhaps the `calendar` is inappropriate? Try setting it to a Gregorian calendar explicitly.

Comment: You might need to set the locale to en_US_POSIX if your current locale doesn't have any of those date components

Comment: Both the Swift and Obj-C code work for me but @Andreus is right.  When you set the date, you did not give a time zone, so it defaulted to UTC.  When you displayed it, it displayed in your local time zone.  Note also that if daylight saving time is used in your locale; 1st April has the daylight saving adjustment but 13 Dec (today) doesn't.  (Or vv if you're in the southern hemisphere.)

Comment: How did you stumble over this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Test code:

```
import Foundation

for timeZoneId in TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers {
    let dateString = "1994-04-01"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: timeZoneId)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    if dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) == nil {
        print(timeZoneId)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Asia/Amman
Asia/Damascus
Asia/Gaza
Asia/Hebron
Asia/Jerusalem
```

I conclude your system time zone is set to one of the ones printed. If I type “jerusalem time zone 1994” into Google, [the first result](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/israel/jerusalem?year=1994) tells me that Daylight Saving Time started at midnight on April 1 in 1994. This means there was no midnight. The first instant of April 1, 1994 was in fact 1 AM in that time zone.

A `DateFormatter` uses a time of day of midnight by default when not parsing a time of day from the string. This makes it fail when midnight doesn't exist on the date in the string.

The solution is to not use midnight as your default time of day. Noon is a much safer default time. So, one solution is to include the time of day in the input and parse it in the format:

```
    let dateString = "1994-04-01 12:00:00"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: timeZoneId)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

Another solution is to give the date formatter a default date that is noon of some day:

```
    // Reference date was 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001. This is noon of the same day in UTC.
    dateFormatter.defaultDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 12*60*60)
```

If you are going to do any date parsing or manipulation on iOS or macOS, it would be a **very** good idea to watch [WWDC 2013 Session 227: Solutions to Common Date and Time Challenges](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/227/).

Comment: Outstanding bit of detective work. It's very strange that a particular date-only date string fails to convert on the "crossover day" for daylight savings time. Seems wrong.

Comment: Instead of forcing the time of the date in question to noon, wouldn't it be better to set the time zone of the date formatter to UTC though, since UTC does not have daylight savings time?

Comment: That really depends on why you're parsing the string. Watch the WWDC session.